# Abstracting rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to replace the normal `/users/:id` route that is created by the `resources` command, with a more abstract `/profile` route. It won't be possible to view other users profiles in my app, and therefor the current route is unnecessary specific.

I have tried to overwrite the route created by 'resources :users' with:

```
get '/profile', to: 'users#show'
```

and other variances and combinations, but can't seem to get it right. Either the controller can't find the user because of a missing `id` or it simply can't find the route.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: /users/me could be a better route, otherwise, create a profile controller with its own logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in routes.rb file:

```
resources :users, :except => :show
  collection do
    get 'profile', :action => 'show'
  end
end
```

It will generate url "/users/profile".

But, if u want to use only '/profile', then don't create route as collection inside users resources block.

```
resources :users, :except => :show
get 'profile' => "users#show", :as => :user_profile
```

It will redirect '/profile' to show action in users controller.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest simply adding a `users/me` route pointing to the `show` action of your `UsersController` like so:

```
resources :users, only: [] do
  collection do
    get 'me', action: :show
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the match keyword in routes.rb file.

```
match 'users/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user_profile, via: :get
```